# .net core db connection pool monitoring to sql-server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm using .net core 3.0, Dapper and SQL Server. I've got couple of rest controllers that connects to SQL server and do some selects. My app is running on Linux Alpine in Docker container in Kubernetes.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.AddTransient(db => new SqlConnection(sqlServer));
    ...
    services.AddTransient<MyRepository>();
    ...
}
```

MyRepository.cs

```
public class MyRepository 
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _connection;

    public DepositDataRepository(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    ...

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyObj>> GetMyObjs(Guid userId)
    {
        return await _connection.QueryAsync<MyObj>("some simple sql goes here", new {userId = userId});
    }
}
```

MyController.cs

```
[Route("/myobjects")]
[ApiController]
[AccessTokenValidator]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public BeneficiaryController(MyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<MyObj>>> Get()
    {
        var entities = await _repository.GetMyObjs(Guid.NewGuid());
        return Ok(entities);
    }
}
```

I do multiple parallel calls to my rest controllers which uses repositories (transient inject).

I measure request processing time on server using middleware - it is around 6 seconds per call, what is really slow. Part of the calls are executed in 300 milliseconds.

I measure time execution of _connection.QueryAsync itself - it is around 200-300 milliseconds.

Connection pool is enabled (using all defaults).

I would like to find out how many alive db connections I have in the pool before I call DB. To make sure, that infrastructure that I have, do not kill connections somehow.

There are PerformanceCounter's on Windows (also shows pool info), but this is not supported in Alpine.

How can I monitor my connection pool?

Comment: The problem is the code, not the pool. Don't use transient. Don't inject the connection. Connections should live only as long as needed and get closed/dispose as soon as possible. `Transient` doesn't call `Dispose()`. Dapper's `Query<>` doesn't close the connection by itself either. This code leaks connections.

Comment: Connection behind the hood contains static variables for pool - so it should live as long as application, as far as I understand.

Comment: What you need injected is the connection string, not the connection itself.

Comment: `so it should live as long as application` definitely not, and your code does the *opposite* in any case. It creates a *new* connection on each call. The pool is implemented by the database driver, not the connection object. There would be no need for a pool if you could use *one* connection for all calls anyway

Comment: When you *close* a connection, the driver gets the *actual* connection object, resets it (thus rolling back any running transactions and releasing any locks) and puts it back in the connection pool. When you ask for a *new* connection, the driver picks up a connection from that pool and wraps in in a SqlConnection object.

Comment: The main reason you *shouldn't* keep connections open for long, is that any locks acquired while reading, updating etc at the default READ COMMITTED isolation level are kept until the connection closes. Even if you use snapshot isolation, row copies are maintained in tempdb as long as the connection is alive. In the first case this leads to increased blocking, in the second, increased traffic in tempdb. In both cases scalability and performance suffer

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.

Comment: I've found article about dispose
https://andrewlock.net/four-ways-to-dispose-idisposables-in-asp-net-core/ 
and I've done some debug - looks like services.AddTransient(db => new SqlConnection(sqlServer)); call dispose()

Comment: You misunderstood what the article says: `at the end of the request (or more accurately, at the end of a scope),`. The ASP.NET middleware intervenes and handles transient instances as if they were scoped. Without that, the DI container has no idea when to dispose that transient instance. If you add a dependency to your repository class *outside* of a controller's control, the connection won't be disposed

Comment: Looks like we have misunderstanding - I do not use my transient repository in middleware - only in controllers, so it have to be handled by DI container.

Comment: The controller's dependencies are generated by the middleware, not DI directly. That's what makes even transients work as scoped. *DON'T* register the connections as transient anyway. If you have connection issues, something, somewhere isn't disposing those transient connections.

Comment: In any case, the pool contains only *in*active connections. If the queries are slow, troubleshoot *them*. Are they taking excessive locks? Performing full table scans due to missing indexes? Are you executing 10 concurrent INSERTs instead of a single one with 10 records in the VALUES clause? Or executing 10 concurrent SELECTS for 10 IDs instead of a single one with all IDs in an `IN` clause?

Comment: The connection pool won't *slow* things down unless you specify a limit. By default it grows as needed

Comment: We have plain sqls, optimised, no full scans. It seems now, that this is our infrastructure network issue. Thanks for help.